# XUnit: ICollectionFixture instance not getting shared between test methods of a test class

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have created ICollectionFixture implementation in hope to create a database instance and share it among various test classes. But, its just not happening and the DBContext gets created on every test method call. On debugging, I can clearly see that after every test method completion , Dispose method of my InMemoryDbContextFixture class gets called , and so every time , a new instance of DBContext gets created which does not saves any of the data that I passed through my first test method..

[XUnit](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) document clearly says that when you want to create a single test context and share it among tests in several test classes, we can create ICollectionFixture implementation.

What does sharing mean, when we always are creating a new instance of DBContext? Please help me understand such behavior in name of sharing the instance.
I can achieve the present behavior using

> Static classes
> as well. So why to use ICollectionFixture. This interface should prevent me from creating new instance of DBContext for every test case.

My Fixture class goes like

```
 public class InMemoryDbContextFixture : IDisposable
{
    private static bool _isdbInitialized = false;
    static MyDbContext databaseContext = null;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    public InMemoryDbContextFixture()
    {            
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_isdbInitialized)
            {
                var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                           .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                           .Options;

                databaseContext = new MyDbContext(options);

                databaseContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();       //Ensure first old db is deleted.
                databaseContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                _isdbInitialized = true;        //db is initialized for the first time.

                // ... initialize data in the test database ...
                Context = databaseContext;
            }
           
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Context.Dispose();
    }

    public MyDbContext Context
    {
        get { return databaseContext; }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

ICollectionFixture implementation.

```
[CollectionDefinition("SharedTestDatabaseDemo")]
public class SharedTestDatabaseDBContextCollection : ICollectionFixture<InMemoryDbContextFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and should never be created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```

My Test Class

```
//using namespaces
namespace Project.TestControllers
{
    [Collection("SharedTestDatabaseDemo")]
    public class TestAuthController
    {  
        private readonly MyDbContext myDbContext = null;
       

        public TestAuthController(InMemoryDbContextFixture dbcontextForTest)
        {
            //Initialize non-mocked objects.           
            nimblyDbContext = dbcontextForTest.Context;

            //Arrange mocks 

            objAuthCountroller = new AuthController(mock1.Object, configSettings, myDbContext,
               mock2.Object, mock3.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Test_LoginUserWithCorrectCredentials()
        {
            //Arrange dependencies.
            InputModel logincred = new InputModel() {
                Email = "XunitTestUser@testmail.com",
                Password = "Pass@9799",
                RememberMe = true
            };

            myDbContext.AspNetUserTokens.Add(new AspNetUserTokens
            {
                UserId = "2",
                LoginProvider = "JWT",
                Name = "XunitTestUser@testmail.com"
            });

            myDbContext.AspNetUsers.Add(new AspNetUsers
            {
                Id = "2",
                Name = "XunitTestUser1",
                UserName = "XunitTestUser1",
                Email = "XunitTestUser@testmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "XUNITTESTUSER@TESTMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true
            });
           
            await myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            

            //ACT
            var result = await objAuthCountroller.Login(logincred);
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Test_ShouldNotAuthenticateUserWithInvalidPassword()
        {
            InputModel logincred = new InputModel();

            logincred.Email = "rahul@testmail.com";
            logincred.Password = "InvalidPassword";
            logincred.RememberMe = true;           
           var result = await objAuthCountroller.Login(logincred);
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took your code and it works well. Dispose was called once when testing `TestAuthController` class. Why not use [WebAppFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and configure InMemory db context using `ConfigureTestServices()` in overriden web factory `ConfigureWebHost` method?

Comment: @Prolog Yes, I was trying that way....had already written the code for that approach...But then suddenly I thought to run the test project with all test cases...and then I saw ICollectionFixture working as per its documentation..in way that it should work..
So I am planning to freeze this code only as WebAppFactory seems to be more complex code to me...than the above that I have written..

Thanks for the support..

Comment: Agree, properly configuring WebApplicationFactory can be a pain. Though, maybe you find [this piece of code](https://gitlab.com/Prologh/parking-lot/-/blob/development/test/IntegrationTests/ParkingLotWebAppFactory.cs) from my privite project helpful. Otherwise, MS documentation and Stack Overflow should be enough to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, on running all the test cases at one go, I got the answer..

Actually , we might get this issue when we are trying to test only one Test method and not the entire Test Project. I got confused because when trying to debug Test methods individually in the test class.

Now, when I run all the run cases in visual studio , I can clearly see that `ICollectionFixture` instance is created only once and shared among various test classes using the collection.